# PHP require_once sem a necessidade de passar o caminho completo

Tags: php, servidor, include, require

Estou com um projeto legado, onde todos os arquivos PHP fazem conexão com o banco através do arquivo "oracle_ado.php"

Este arquivo está na pasta "../inc/" e o restante na pasta "../prod/".

Estou montando outro servidor para essa aplicação, onde os arquivos da pasta "../prod/" não encontram o arquivo "oracle_ado.php"

O require está da seguinte maneira...

```
require_once ('oracle_ado.php');
```

sendo que se altero para...

```
require_once ('../inc/oracle_ado.php');
```

a aplicação roda sem problemas.

No servidor atual roda sem a necessidade de informar o caminho "../inc/", alguém sabe me dizer o que pode ser? O que falta configurar no servidor novo?

Ambos servidores Linux

Comment: É um servidor linux ou windows ?

Comment: Opa, desculpa... é Linux, vou editar na pergunta

Comment: Navega pelo terminal até a pasta raiz da um 'ls -l', da o comando na pasta 'inc' e tbm da o mesmo comando na pasta 'prod', faz isso nos dois servers, e verifica se o arquivo 'oracle_ado.php' não foi parar na pasta prod, acho que a única explicação é ter misturado os arquivos

Comment: O melhor seria usar um `autoloader`, assim sempre chama somente ele ao invés das classes.

Comment: Olá Raoni, pois é eu também acho... Mas queria justamente evitar ter que editar todos os arquivos.

Comment: Se vocÊ da um error_reporting(E_ALL) no arquivo quando não funciona, que resposta que ele te da ?

Comment: O que apareceu foi 22519, sobre o ls -l, está exatamente igual ao servidor atual

Answer (score 1):

o que deve ter nesse servidor que está rodando dentro da configuração do PHP no php.ini um redirecionamento na variável ;include_path = ".:/caminho/inc:/caminho/prod" ai deve estar o caminho absoluto da pasta inc, ou outras pastas por isso deve funcionar de boa, no servidor novo se você configurar assim também deve funcionar, mas a sugestão é você usar os hosts e realizar nele se você usa, senão todas as outras aplicações rodando terão acesso aos arquivos já que fica global essa configuração no servidor.

Comment: O include_path do novo servidor também está exatamente igual ao servidor atual.

include_path = ".:/usr/share/pear:/usr/local/jpgraph:/u01/desenv/inc"

Sendo que nas pastas existem os mesmos arquivos

Comment: quando você chama o require ou include ele te retorna algum erro do PHP como failed to open stream?

Comment: Olá Paulo, não tive nenhum erro, simplesmente parou quando chamei um método do "oracle_ado.php". Também incluí o caminho do inc no include_path, mesmo assim não funcionou. Estou com isso no "stand-by", pois tive que liberar o micro com o "servidor novo". Creio que amanhã consigo dar prosseguimento a essa tarefa.